# Django custom decorator with cache_page error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-1.5, python-decorators

I have a custom decorator on a view and i have to cache that view after processing some request variables. My decorator code is like this

```
def custom_dec(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
    def wrapper(request,filters,*args,**kwargs):
        # do some processing on request and filters
        return csrf_exempt(cache_page(900, view_func))
return wrapper
```

and i have applied the decorator as :

```
@custom_dec
def myview(request,filters,*args,**kwargs):
    # view code here
```

The problem is running this code gives me an error when going through the middleware :

Exception Type: AttributeError 
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'

When i look the at respone it's the function myview instead of the response of the view.
response `<function myview at 0xb549e534>`

What is wrong in my code?

UPDATE: The code runs fine if i change the return in warpper function to 
 `return view_func` which means i must be doing something wrong in applying cache page decorator.

Comment: Are you returning HttpResonse object from your view? Post the full view code here as is.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy : yes, the view code works without this decorator.

Comment: Nope.In that case it does not work. you need to return HttpResponse object from that view even though you are caching.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy I didn't understand, the view renders a template with render_to_response. I used simple cache(900) decorator on the view and it worked. This custom decorator is giving me problems.

Comment: That's cause you is return function, not a response object.

Comment: @Denis : i didn't understand that?

Comment: just run your function and it should return response object which has status_code and other attrs.

Comment: @Denis i am running it that's when i get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to return an HttpResponse object. It worked when i changed the code to :

```
def custom_dec(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
    def wrapper(request,filters,*args,**kwargs):
        # do some processing on request and filters
        cached_func = cache_page(900, view_func)
        return cached_func(request,filters,*args,**kwargs) #this returns an HttpResponse object
        # the above two line could also be written as cache_page(900, view_func)(request,filters,*args,**kwargs)
return wrapper
```